# RPM: Can it do this?

Tags: rpm

New here.  I have a generalized question regarding something I'd like to do but am not familiar enough to know before I embark on a path I may not ever be able to complete.

I've developed a shell script and supporting shell code to install a vendor relational database product.  I'd like to wrap all this into RPM package that will operate primarily on AIX and Linux platforms.

Can I build an RPM package to take this vendor tar-ball and using my shell script install this vendor product?  There's no source or anything to compile, it's a tar-ball that would extract into a temp location (would love to use a ramdisk) then my script would spawn from the RPM and do all the remaining tasks like running the vendor installation program as well as many other things we do, prechecks, post-checks and validations.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you **can** do that, but it would be cleaner if you would:

- extract the files and 'install' them at the correct location during the **building** of your `rpm`
- run your pre/post checks upon **installation**

this way you don't need to package the whole tarball inside your rpm, and the final files belong to your `rpm` package. All files that you create in your `%post` scripts etc don't belong to your package, which is bad practice (since then they won't be removed when you uninstall the `rpm` package for example).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That's was the reason I asked,  I actually can't or shouldn't do that install into the buildroot because being a large scale relational database product it may not install into my buildroot as all the configurations wouldn't be there to service the product.

Comment: This RPM would only be executed on a server "expecting" this relational database product and therefore all the configuration pieces present from which the vendor installer within their tar-ball would successfully install.

Comment: I'll give this a go at least knowing it's possible to do what I intended to do.  I may be back here for more questions.  thanks again.